# Vue.js- How is the value of v-model and this.pageNumber are changing according to the pagination?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-component, v-model

```
<v-pagination
     v-model="pageNumber"
     :length="numberOfPages"
     color="primary"
      totalVisible="5"
      class="paginationComponent"
      @update:modelValue="changePage()">
</v-pagination>

<script>
export default {
  data: () => ({
    pageNumber: 1,
 })
}
methods: {
    init() {
      axios({
        method: "get",
        url: "/products",
        params: {
          size: 10,
          page: this.pageNumber - 1,
        },
      })
        .then((response) => {
          console.log('Success');
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error(error);
        });
    },
    changePage() {
      console.log(this.pageNumber);
      this.init();
    },
</script>
```

[Pagination Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZyrNi.png)

I am pretty new to Vue.js. Every time I click on a page number, the exact number is being logged into the console. I am unable to understand how it is recognizing that number. I thought there is a logic in the method which adds or subtracts the number to/from the default pageNumber value. But there's no such thing. With correct pageNumber the api takes care of rest of the work.

Before this process, I tried accessing the text content of the pageNumber element with children elements all the unnecessary weird stuff.

Comment: `<v-pagination>` is a [component](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/component-basics.html).  Just like any component, it has it's own internal data and methods where it does many things including keeping track of, modifying, and emitting the value of the page number.  If you had to keep track of and modify the data yourself, it wouldn't be a very useful component.  You can find the source code, though it is a bit complicated, on the [Vuetify github](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/master/packages/vuetify/src/components/VPagination/VPagination.tsx)

Comment: The value is kept up to date through two-way binding with [`v-model`](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/v-model.html). You have set a listener to the same event that `v-model` listens to (`@update:modelValue`), so now when the even arrives, the value is first updated from `v-model`, and then `changePage()` is called.

Answer (score 1):

```js
<v-pagination
     v-model="pageNumber"
      @update:modelValue="changePage()">
</v-pagination>
```

Same as

```js
<v-pagination
     v-bind:value="pageNumber"
      @update:modelValue="number => { pageNumber = number;changePage(); }">
</v-pagination>
```

In `v-pagination` component, click page number button

```js
//Click handler code
emit('update:modelValue', pageNumber);
```

Recommended

```js
<v-pagination
     v-model="pageNumber"
     :length="numberOfPages"
     color="primary"
     totalVisible="5"
     class="paginationComponent">
</v-pagination>

<script>
export default {
  data: () => ({
    pageNumber: 1,
  }),
  watch: {
      pageNumber(newValue, oldValue) {
          console.log(newValue);
          this.init(newValue);
      }
  },
  methods: {
    init(pageNumber) {
      axios({
        method: "get",
        url: "/products",
        params: {
          size: 10,
          page: pageNumber - 1,
        },
      })
        .then((response) => {
          console.log('Success');
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error(error);
        });
    }
}
```